# Importing PST Calendar to Outlook.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have an existing Outlook .pst file with a calendar, which I want to import to my Outlook.com account. I've tried importing it on outlook.com, but receive "calendar unavailable". Are there any other methods of doing this?

Comment: You don't say how you are trying to import the Calendar - please could you clarify what you are doing. Also, is this Outlook.com or Outlook365 and are you connecting to email via the web browser interface or through an email application (such as Outlook)

Comment: @misterjaytee, I am trying to import to Outlook.com. I've tried doing so through Outlook.com's Calendar page, which gave the above error. I want to know if there is a different method (whether through the desktop or .com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to hook up Outlook to your Outlook.com account and then do the PST import from Outlook. However you need to set the account up as an IMAP account (in Outlook) and not an Activesync account (the Activesync method will give an error stating that the service provider does not support this).

Settings to use for IMAP:

**Incoming IMAP**

- Server: imap-mail.outlook.com
- Server port: 993
- Encryption: SSL

-

**Outgoing SMTP**

- Server: smtp-mail.outlook.com
- Server port: 587
- Encryption: TLS

(Also check the "My outgoing server (SMTP) requires authentication" if you're going to use Outlook to do more than just the Calendar import - i.e. to send email)

Comment: P.S. This may work on Windows Live Mail, but I've not tested it as I don't use it - however I have tested the Outlook method.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. I also found that outlook lets you export the calendar as an ics (Calendar->File->Save Calendar), which you can then import much more easily than a pst file.